# use of undeclared identifier 'GMSServices' in Visual Studio 2015 in WinObjC

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, visual-studio-2015, cocoapods, winobjc

I used pod in my objective-c code.
But when I Use this code to visual studio at that time it give errors :

1) use of undeclared identifier `'GMSServices'`

2) expected identifier or '(' \Pods\Headers\Public\GoogleMaps\GoogleMaps\GoogleMaps.h

But when I click 2) Error it showing a popup

[image: This document is opened by another project.]

I thought may be it's a Pod error so again I took my fresh code and I tried to install **vsimporter**. At that time I checked that Pod installation failed. The following error came when I installed **vsimporter**:

[image: Pod Error]

And I also noticed that in visual studio solution explorer it showing me as 3 Projects

[image: Solution Explorer]

So, was I missed the file structure? IS there any specific file structure to put in visual studio?

Please help me to solve this issues. I am new in visual studio. And I already Post this Question in WinObjC Github.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods are not currently supported by the bridge as our clang compiler front end does not support virtual filesystems, which CocoaPods depends on. It's a feature request we get a lot, so we're investigating adding support, but in the meantime you can try removing CocoaPods and manually including your third party libraries before running vsimporter.

Comment: ok thanks . I tried with my old code which have not use CocoaPods. But it give me error **'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file  not found.** and also I found another error:

**no visible @interface for 'UISlider' declares the selector 'setValue:animated:'**